# How to sort dataframe by value in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a data set in csv that I read with `pd.read_csv.` I want to sort the esxisting data by descanding value.

my code is this:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('Kripto.csv')
sorted = dataset.sort_values(by = "Freq1", ascending=False)

x = dataset.iloc[:, :].values
```

and my data set (print(dataset)) is this :

```
 Letter;Freq1

0      A;0.0817

1      B;0.0150

2      C;0.0278

3      D;0.0425

4      E;0.1270
```

when i want to use this code:

```
sorted = dataset.sort_values(by = "Freq1", ascending=False)
```

python gives me an error and says KeyError: 'Freq1'

I know that "Freq1" is not the name of the column but ı have no idea how to assing a name

Comment: `dataset = pd.read_csv('Kripto.csv', sep=';')` would fix your problem.

Comment: Note that sorting is almost only useful for printing (that is, for humans); especially when you are working with dataframes, since selections are normally done on other criteria than the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your csv file has " ; " as separator, you need to indicate on the read_csv method:

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('your.csv', sep=';')
```

And that's all you need to do

Answer (score 1):

Your CSV file uses semi-colons to separate values. Since Pandas by defaults expects comma's, use

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('Kripto.csv', sep=';')
```

instead.

You should also use the `sorted` dataset to get your values in sorted order, instead of `dataset`, since the latter will remain unsorted:

```
x = sorted.iloc[:, :].values
```